# how to adjust all the character in android place autocomplete fragment

Tags: android, google-api

in my place autocomplete fragment i am not able to see the character as searched. Suppose if the searched place is too  long , it only shows few character . How to make it multi line or something so that it will be visible .

Answer (score 0):

To partially solve your issue, you can split the result so the place name is on a separate line from the address.  Like

Starbucks
111 Birdy Lane SE, Redmond, WA 99999

You might be able to reduce the font size, which could also display more characters.  To split the lines, go to your PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter, and search for "resultList.add".  It probably looks something like this:

```
resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),
                            prediction.getFullText(null));
```

Change it to:

```
resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),
                            prediction.getPrimaryText(null),
                            prediction.getSecondaryText(null)));
```

Then in "class PlaceAutocomplete" modify the constructor so it looks like this:

```
    PlaceAutocomplete(CharSequence placeId, CharSequence primary, CharSequence secondary) {
        this.placeId = placeId;
        this.description = primary + "\n" + secondary;
    }
```

Alternatively, you could avoid changing the call and the constructor, and in the assignment to this.description, replace the first comma with "\n".  Either way works, I suggested the first approach because it doesn't rely on existence of a comma in the correct location.